# Evaluate multiple variables in one 'if' statement?

Tags: python, if-statement

Say I have a bunch of variables that are either `True` or `False`.  I want to evaluate a set of these variables in one if statement to see if they are all `False` like so:

```
if var1, var2, var3, var4 == False:
    # do stuff
```

Except that doesn't work. I know I can do this:

```
if var1 == False and var2 == False and var3 == False and var4 == False:
    # do stuff
```

But that's fairly ugly - especially if these if statements are going to occur a lot in my code. Is there any sort of way I can do this evaluation with a cleaner syntax (like the first example)?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You should [never test a boolean variable with `== True` (or `== False`)](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/12807/make-a-big-deal-out-of-true). Instead, either write:

```
if not (var1 or var2 or var3 or var4):
```

or use [`any`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#any) (and in related problems its cousin [`all`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#all)):

```
if not any((var1, var2, var3, var4)):
```

or use Python's [transitive comparisons](http://docs.python.org/reference/expressions.html#not-in):

```
if var1 == var2 == var3 == var4 == False:
```

Comment: `not any(...)` is the Pythonic way to do it for the "all False" case, and `all(...)` is for the "all True" case.

Comment: `any((var1, var2, var3, var4))` means all will be evaluated regardless which  if you were using expensive  functions would be pretty inefficient and rather defeats the purpose of any and short circuiting

Comment: @PadraicCunningham `var1`, `var2` etc. are all variables, hence the `var`. If they are function calls, you would of cause use something else.

Answer (score 7):

How about this:

```
# if all are False
if not any([var1, var2, var3, var4]):
    # do stuff
```

or:

```
# if all are True
if all([var1, var2, var3, var4]):
    # do stuff
```

These are easy to read, since they are in plain English.

Answer (score 3):

You can do:

```
if var1 and var2 and var3 and var4:
     do stuff
```

Answer (score 3):

`if all(not v for v in (var1, var2, var3, var4)):`

That's for the "all false" branch. For "all true", just do `if all((var2, var2, var3, var4)):`.

Comment: all false can be shortened to : `if not any((var1, var2, var3, var4)):`

Comment: @soulcheck You need to put the arguments into an iterable. `any` takes only one argument.

Comment: Not necessary to use `not`, and it can make mistakes easier.

Answer (score 1):

What about a custom function?

```
function ListObjectsEqualTo(myList, toValue):
    for i in myList:
        if i != toValue:
            return False
    return True
```

Now you can use it

```
if ListObjectsEqualTo((var1, var2, var3, var4), False):
    # do stuff
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do:

```
if var1 == var2 == var3 == var4 == False:
  do_stuff()
```

But, if the variables evaluate to true or false, you could also do this:

```
if var1 and var2 and var3 and var4:
  do_stuff()
```

Or

```
if all([var1, var2, var3, var4]):
  do_stuff()
```

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> not any([False, False])
True
>>> not any([True, False])
False
>>>
```

Use the [any()](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#all) keyword.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `if var1 == var2 == var3 == False:`