# 'float' object is not callable, in one instance but works in another

Tags: python, python-3.x

This is the code, it should take an average of ether x or y coordinates when called how ever when y is called it gives an error.

```
import turtle
turtle.setup()
A = turtle.Turtle()

####################################################
total_of_x_scores = 0
total_of_y_scores = 0
number_of_x_scores = 0
number_of_y_scores = 0
average = 0

def average(axis):
    global total_of_x_scores
    global total_of_y_scores
    global number_of_x_scores
    global number_of_y_scores
    global average
    if axis=='x'or'X':
        x=A.xcor()
        total_of_x_scores += x #adding curent score
        number_of_x_scores += 1
        average=total_of_x_scores/number_of_x_scores
    else:
        y=A.ycor()
        total_of_y_scores += y #adding curent score
        number_of_y_scores += 1
        average=total_of_y_scores/number_of_y_scores
    return average
######################################################

while True:
    A.goto(100,100)
    print('x',average('x'))
    print('y',average('y'))
```

and this is the error, notice that it doesn't error on the x

```
x 100.0
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "C:/Users/Jack/Desktop/average def.py", line 34, in <module>
    print('y',average('y'))
TypeError: 'float' object is not callable
```

Comment: you have a variable and function named `average`. Rename one of them

Comment: will do, thanks, didn't notice

Comment: that appears to fix the problem

Comment: `axis=='x'or'X'` is not how python conditionals work https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9504638/

Comment: There doesn't seem to be any reason to have those globals.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even though you start out defining `average` as a number, you subsequently define `average` as a function.  So the first time you call `average()`, it rightly understands it as a function.  But since `average` is global, when the function completes, `average` is back to being a number again.

Here's a demonstration of the issue:

```
foo = 0

def foo():
    global foo
    foo = 1.0
    return foo

print('now foo is:', foo, 'and foo class is:', type(foo))
print('call foo() to get foo =', foo())
print('now foo is:', foo, 'and foo class is:', type(foo))
print('call foo() to get foo =', foo())
```

Output:

```
now foo is: <function foo at 0x1a27e108c8> and foo class is: <class 'function'>
call foo() to get foo = 1.0
now foo is: 1.0 and foo class is: <class 'float'>
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1138-008d99aeffef> in <module>()
      2 print('call foo() to get foo =', foo())
      3 print('now foo is:', foo, 'and foo class is:', type(foo))
----> 4 print('call foo() to get foo =', foo())

TypeError: 'float' object is not callable
```